# using the functions in the code generated by lex and yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

I want to write a minimalistic XML parser for my timetabling application. I do no want to use any libraries or parsers that will support XML parsing because they be less efficient for my use(as I only need to recognize a few tags only). Hence I have decided to write a parser using lex and yacc.
Is there any way that I can use the functions in the .h file created by lex and yacc in my code directly rather than writing the application code in the yacc itself.

Answer (score 1):

The functions exported by your lex and yacc generated programs are minimal. The parser is invoked by calling `yyparse`. It calls `yylex` in the lexer. Everything else can be outside.

It is convenient and customary to have some parsing support routines in the lex and yacc files themselves (helpers which are called by lexing and parsing actions, and not by anything else). But not the application logic. (Except for very trivial textbook examples for Yacc.)